# Implementing a simple CPU meter

Tags: user-interface, plot, real-time

I'd like to implement a real time plot of my CPU and GPU load. 
I already have a script that retrieve the data and echo it in a terminal.
What I want to do now is to plot this information to see the evolution with time.
I don't know if I need python for instance, and in this case using which module?
Is there any other alternative?
Does someone have any experience doing real time plotting?

Éric.

---

here is what I did so far

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import pylab
import time

t = 0
dt = .25
old = None

if __name__ == "__main__":
  pylab.ion()
  #pylab.xlabel('this is x!')
  #pylab.ylabel('this is y!')
  #pylab.title('My First Plot')
  while True:
      with open('/proc/stat') as stat:
              new = map(float, stat.readline().strip().split()[1:])     
      if old is not None:
            diff = [n - o for n, o in zip(new, old)]
            idle = diff[3] / sum(diff)  
        pylab.clf()
        pylab.plot(t,int(255 * (1 - idle)),'-b', label='cpu')
        #print t,int(255 * (1 - idle))
        pylab.draw()
      old = new
          time.sleep(dt)
      t = t + dt
```

Well, something happens when I execute it but nothing is displayed. 
Any suggestion?
Thank you,

Éric.

Comment: this looks interesting: http://www.gnu.org/software/plotutils/  (although, I haven't used it so I cannot vouch for it)

Comment: thanks, I'll take a look at it. So far I tried using pylab but unsuccessfully.